# Random insert, Random get C# Collection

Tags: c#, data-structures, collections

I need a C# collection from which I can as quickly as possible pick out a random element, but also add new elements to. It is for a scrabble bag of letter blocks. Which one should I use?

Comment: many data structures fit the bill. how about a List?

Comment: Why as quickly as possible? Are you running simulations or games against real humans?

Comment: You only need the insert (or just the read) to be randomised.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I'll try with a List<String>. Since I need it for a scrabble bag of letters, I need to be able to pick up a random blocks, as well as put back blocks. I think this should be possible by taking random index as Jamiec said. Than I can probably just add new blocks to the end of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything implementing `IList` (or, more probably `IList<T>`) as these can be referenced by index. Its very easy to pick a random number in the range `0 < n < list.Count-1` and get that item from the list.

eg/

```
// assumes 'random' is an instance of System.Random
myRandomElement = myList[random.Next(0,myList.Count-1)]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `List<T>`.
It depends what you want to keep in that list too.

Answer (score 2):

[Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

> The Dictionary generic class provides a mapping from a
>   set of keys to a set of values. Each addition to the dictionary
>   consists of a value and its associated key. **Retrieving a value by
>   using its key is very fast, close to O(1)**, because the
>   Dictionary class is implemented as a hash table.

Edit: Ok, I thought you need to specify keys or something.

What is wrong with List<> ?

Comment: Why would you need a dictionary? OP just wants a random entry.

Comment: Right, that's why I put the "Edit" note :).

Answer (score 0):

If you want speed I suggest a     Dictionairy

Comment: Why would you need a dictionary? OP just wants a random entry.